# Guake terminal with 256 colors?

Tags: terminal, xterm, vte, 256color

Is it possible to make Guake terminal to use 256 colors instead of just 8?

The only info that I found on the internet is this post https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173707 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Guake* supports natively 256 colours. And **this** is the answer to your question ;)

For testing it, you can simply run [this](https://github.com/l0b0/xterm-color-count) script.

Answer (score 1):

Ok fixed: You just need to run this scripts provided here:

https://github.com/coolwanglu/guake-colors-solarized

Comment: Well, you have found a workaround and made *solarized* work (almost) fine for you. Have you perhaps found out if *Guake* can support 256 colours instead?